# React Native library to track user location

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-maps

Which library will be most suitable for Android and iOS to be able to track user location continuously even if the app is running in background.

I need to track user's location to send notification that the user has entered a specific location and upon exiting the user has left the location.

Comment: Sounds like you should be using a [`Geofence`](https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing). Note that on Android 8.0 an later, if your app is running in the background there might be a couple of minutes between geofencing events. That's just a how Android works, and I don't think there's much you can do about that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use geolocation like this way:

```
 getUserCurrentLocation = async () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {
                const { latitude, longitude } = position.coords;
                resolve({ lat: latitude, lng: longitude })
            }, error => {
                console.log(`ERROR(${error.code}): ${error.message}`);
                resolve({ error })
            } // , { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 10000, maximumAge: 1000 }
            );
            setTimeout(() => { resolve({ error: { code: 3 } }) }, 5000);
        } catch (e) {
            resolve({ error: { code: 3 } })
        }
    })
};
```

Comment: @user11426267 If it's help and solution your problem please mark the answer as correct

Comment: what the problem?